# Angular 5 + Ngrx correct schema

Tags: angular5, ngrx, state-management

just recently started using ngrx as a means for state management with my angular 5 application. My application is simple, 6 pages with a form on each page.

I would like to add state management to this application, and I have started. However would like assurance if this is the correct way to approach this.

I have created a reducer for each page, and each page has it's own state. ReducerPage1State, ReducerPage2State for example.

When the application re-starts and the app is hydrated with the previous state of the client, would I populate all the state reducers via a parent reducer such as app reducer with holds a giant object of the application state and feeds it to the other reducers?

Kind of confused with this. What would be the correct approach to saving the state of this application (6 pages with a form on each page) and reloading it on the next visit.

For example, page 1 is personal Info -- how should I populate the initial state? currently from adapter,but initial state will be null.I want to get previous state from an API call or some thing etc.

```
export interface PersonalInfoState extends EntityState<PersonalInformation> {
personalInfo: PersonalInformation;
```

}

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<PersonalInformation> = createEntityAdapter();

const initialState: PersonalInfoState = adapter.getInitialState({
    personalInfo: null
});
```

Comment: Where are you persisting the state (db, local storage, ...)?

Comment: at the end of each page, I will be uploading to DB so that next time the app loads, its retrieved from DB. but the state should also be local etc. Just launching an effect on page complete to call db to upload and then route to the next page.

Comment: I was trying to see if you could use a factory provider to get the data async and provide it for the INITIAL_STATE token but I don't see anything about doing an async factory provider.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but should it rather be anothe rreducer, such as appReducer rather than page1Reducer etc, that has an action+effect that retrieves state from server.

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense. Have a meta-reducer that can set all of state and an effect that auto fires to retrieve state.